# Angular 2 Component Router

Tags: angular, angular-new-router

I am going crazy trying to setup a simple test app on Angular 2. I have 3 pages/components that I want to load with the new Component Router. I've gotten it to semi work. Currently I have two problems...

**1 -** If  you type the path of the component you want to go to Ex. "http://127.0.0.1:8080/Test2" instead of loading my Test2 page, it fails saying that it can't find that route.

**2 -** When trying to load different pages, the first time that I click on a link, it will properly load the page. All other pages will throw an exception when I click on a link.

This is my setup:

**App.ts**

```
import {Component, bootstrap, provide} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouteConfig, APP_BASE_HREF} from 'angular2/router';

import {Test1} from './Test1';
import {Test2} from './Test2';
import {Test3} from './Test3';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<test1></test1><router-outlet></router-outlet>',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Test1, Test2]
})

@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/', as: 'Home', component: Test1},
  {path: '/Test2', as: 'Test2', component: Test2},
  {path: '/Test3', as: 'Test3', component: Test3}   
])

class AppComponent {
  constructor() {}
 }

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, provide(APP_BASE_HREF, { useValue: '/' })]);
```

**Test1.ts**

```
import {Component, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {RouterLink} from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'test1',
    templateUrl: 'app/Test1.html',
    directives: [RouterLink] 
})
export class Test1 { }
```

**Test1.html**

```
<h1> Test 1 </h1>
<a [router-link]="['/Test2']">Test Link 2</a>
```

**Test2.ts**

```
import {Component, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {RouterLink} from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'test2',
    templateUrl: 'app/Test2.html',
    directives: [RouterLink]
})
export class Test2 { }
```

**Test2.html**

```
<h1> Test 2 </h1>
<a [router-link]="['/Test3']">Test Link 3</a>
```

**Test3.ts**

```
import {Component, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {RouterLink} from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'test3',
    templateUrl: 'app/Test3.html',
    directives: [RouterLink]
})
export class Test3 { }
```

**Test3.html**

```
<h1> Test 3 </h1>
<a [router-link]="['/Test2']">Test Link 2</a>
```

Thanks for the help guys!

**Yakov's LocationStrategy suggestion fixed the problem.** For anyone having the same issue, the full working code at https://github.com/zorthgo/Angular2QuickstartTest, and the working version of my App.ts looks like this:

```
import {Component, bootstrap, provide} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouteConfig, APP_BASE_HREF, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from 'angular2/router';

import {Test1} from './Test1';
import {Test2} from './Test2';
import {Test3} from './Test3';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: ` <a [router-link]="['/Home']">Test1 Link</a>
                <a [router-link]="['/Test2', {id: 3}]">Test2 Link</a>
                <a [router-link]="['/Test3']">Test3 Link</a>
                <router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Test1, Test2,Test3]
})

@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/',          component: Test1, as: 'Home'},
  {path: '/Test2/:id', component: Test2, as: 'Test2'},
  {path: '/Test3',     component: Test3, as: 'Test3'}

])

class AppComponent {
  constructor() { }
 }

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy })]);
```

Comment: I think `test3.ts @Component` should have `templateurl:'app/Test3.html'`

Comment: 1 comes because you are using the standard html5 based location change. In such a case the server infrastructure should do url redirect so that correct content (root content) is loaded irrespective of the url hit.

Comment: Hi Chandemani, thanks for pointing that out! I've edited the test3 template Url. 

Well, but I am sure that must be a way to load different pages just by typing their URL on the address bar. I just can't seem to get that to work. When I click on the first link, the address displays the correct path. But if I refresh or try to go directly to that location I get a **Cannot GET /Test2**.

Comment: I have a working sample here if that helps:http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/routing-in-angular-2.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did something similar and it works. Try this:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Yakov! That worked prefectly. :)

Comment: Had some problems with this as well, works like a charm!

Comment: can we use `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` in bootstrap function parameters?

Comment: exactly don't now  but normally we use only PROVIDERS at the time of bootstraping your app